# How can I force the default XML namespace to be listed first?

Tags: .net, xml, xml-serialization, xml-namespaces

I am working with an xml specification from outside my organization. I need to generate an xml file that complies with the spec. The file will not validate properly unless the default namespace `xmlns="ndnqi"` is listed first on the root element like so:

```
<HospYearQtr xmlns="ndnqi" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="ndnqi NDNQIV10.xsd">
```

I generated classes from the XSD using xsd.exe and when I serialize to xml it puts the default namespace `xmlns` at the end of the root element.

Is there any way to force the default namespace to be listed first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, get them to fix their broken parser. Attributes in XSD described XML are not ordered items.

Barring that you'll probably need to do something like a Regex replace after generating the content. Something like the code below should be a useful starting point.

```
Regex moveDefaultNamespace = new Regex(@"(<\w+)\s+(.*?)(xmlns="".+?"")\s+(.*?>)");
string xmlText = "<HospYearQ1tr xmlns=\"ndnqi\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"ndnqi NDNQIV10.xsd\">";
string reordered = moveDefaultNamespace.Replace(xmlText, "$1 $2 $3 $4");
```